# Maven jar plugin - Wrong Class-Path entry for SNAPSHOT dependency

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am using `maven-jar-plugin` to build jar and `maven-assembly-plugin` to put all dependencies next to the `JAR` in `lib/`directory.

If I use snapshot dependency this project, the Class-Path entry points do different `JAR` of that dependency, then the actual packaged one.

Here is an example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

`JAR` that is packaged for that dependency inti `lib` direcotyr is
`artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT` but `Class-Path` entry in main `JAR`s manifest is `lib/artifact-1.0-20170201.104414-8.jar`

What is happening here and why?

Thanks in advance.

My assembly.xml

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

Plugins:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>attached</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                    <finalName>${dist.name}</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptor>${basedir}/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                </manifest>
                <manifestEntries>
                    <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
            <outputDirectory>${dist.dir}</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test-jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have been hit by [MJAR-156](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAR-156), which is currently unresolved as of the latest 3.0.2. The core issue is with the downstream [Maven Archiver](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver) library, most probably [MSHARED-169](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHARED-169).

You can workaround that quite easily by specifying Maven Archiver not to create unique versions for snapshots. This is controlled by the parameter [`useUniqueVersions`](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html#class_manifest) under the manifest configuration, which defaults to `true`. As such, you can change the configuration of the Jar Plugin to:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
        <useUniqueVersions>false</useUniqueVersions>
      </manifest>
      <!-- rest of configuration -->
    </archive>
    <outputDirectory>${dist.dir}</outputDirectory>
  </configuration>
  <!-- the executions -->
</plugin>
```

Note that version 2.3.1 of the Jar Plugin is quite old, you should consider updating to the latest 3.0.2.

Comment: still here with 3.1.0

Comment: 3.2.0 is affected too